# Probability Proof about A and B

Tags: probability, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to formally prove that:

$$P(A) = P(A\wedge \neg B) + P(A\wedge B)$$
so I did like this:

$$P(A\wedge \neg B) + P(A\wedge B)$$

$$=P(A\wedge \neg B) + P(A)\cdot P(B)$$

$$=P(A)\cdot P(\neg B) + P(A)\cdot P(B)$$

$$=P(A)\cdot (1-P(B)) + P(A)\cdot P(B)$$

$$=P(A)-(P(A)\cdot P(B)) + (P(A)\cdot P(B))$$

$$=P(A)-0$$

$$=P(A)$$

Is this a valid formal proof? Did I commit any errors?

**Edit:**

$$P(A\wedge \neg B) + P(A\wedge B)$$
$$= P((A\wedge \neg B) \lor (A\wedge B))$$
$$= P(A\wedge (B\lor \neg B))$$
$$= P(A)$$

I'm not sure where to go from here? Does $(B\lor \neg B) = 0?$

Comment: Unless you are assured that $A,B$ are independent you can't assert that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: $P(A\land B)=P(A)P(B)$ is only in very specific cases, not generally true. The theorem is generally true.

Comment: @lulu The question did not state if they were independent or not.

Comment: Right.  So you can't argue that way.

Comment: $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

Comment: @lulu What would I do then? Since this is my first proof writing class.

Comment: @LuisVera is that always true however?

Comment: @Link Yes, it is.

Comment: Most axiom systems for probability use something like $X,Y$ mutually exclusive $\implies P(X)+P(Y)=P(X\cup Y)$.  Start there.

Comment: @LuisVera This is probably stupid, but is U the same thing as ^?

Comment: @Link $\cup \equiv \lor$ and $\cap \equiv \land$. Use the hints they are giving you!

Comment: Alright! Thank you! I'll post an edit once done.

Comment: @LuisVera I tried it like this, I'm not sure if it's right..

Comment: @Link $B \lor \neg B$ is your whole space, what do you get if you intersect your whole space with $A$?

Comment: @LuisVera you get A?

Comment: @Link Correct!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about probability, you usually start with a **probability space** $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, where:

**1.** $\Omega$ is an arbitrary set, called the **sample space**. It is the set of **outcomes**, for example the sample space of a dice roll is $\Omega =\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}.$

**2.** $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$, called **events**. This collection also satisfies certain properties or axioms that (a) involve unions and complements: if $A,B$ are events, then $A\cup B, A^c, B^c$ are also events (the union also holds for **countable** collections of events) and (b) an important subset that always belong to $\mathcal{F}$ (namely $\Omega$). It is what is called a $\sigma$-**algebra**. In the dice roll case, you take the power set $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ as $\mathcal{F}$, and an example of an event $A \in \mathcal{F}$, is that the dice roll is an even number, so $A= \{2\} \cup \{ 4\} \cup \{6\} =\{2,4,6\} \subset \Omega$, so $A \in \mathcal{F}.$

Using these axioms and some properties of the set operations you can see that in every probability space: (a)$\, \emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$ (the empty set), and (b) if $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$, then $A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}.$

**3.** P is a function that sets a value between $0$ and $1$ to each event $ A \in \mathcal{F}$, so $P: \mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$. It is called a **probability measure**, and also satisfy certain axioms: (a) $P(\emptyset)=0$, (b) $P(\Omega)=1$ and (c) $P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + \dots + P(A_n)$ if the sets $A_k$ are **mutually disjoint**, this is $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$, for example. (**This is the hint they gave you**, it is also satisfied if you take a countable collection of events). For the event $A$ in **2.**, for example, $P(A)=P(\{2,4,6\})= P(\{2\}) + P(\{4 \}) + P(\{6\})$, since $A$ is a union of mutually disjoint sets, because the outcome of a dice roll can't be $2$ and $4$ at the same time, etc...

As you can see, when talking about probability, your basic objects of study are sets ($\Omega, A, B$) and functions ($P$), so it is important to learn some properties about them and their operations. The most important operations between sets are the union $A \cup B$, intersection $A \cap B$, difference $A - B$, and complement $A^c = \Omega - A$ (what you write as $\neg B$), and their properties (for example, **associative**, **commutative**, **distributive**, **De Morgan Laws**, etc...) so you can be able to manipulate them.

On the comments and your **edit**, for example, the last question $B \lor \neg B = 0$?, made me think that maybe you don't know some of these important facts, but since you showed interest and work I decided to make this long post so you have some basic definitions. I leave to you the task of researching more about them.

The complete statement and proof of your theorem should be as follows:

**Theorem:** Let ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P$) be a probability space, and $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$. Then 
$$P(A) = P(A \cap B^c) + P(A \cap B).$$

**Proof:** Since $A,B \in \mathcal{F}$, by **2.**, $B^c \in \mathcal{F}$ and also by **2.**, $A \cap B \in \mathcal{F}$ and $ A \cap B^c \in \mathcal{F}$ (This is to ensure that these are in fact events, so we can talk about their probabilities).

$Afirmation \, 1: (A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^c)= \emptyset.$ (that is, this events are mutually disjoint)

$Proof:$ Since $\cap$ is associative and commutative then

$$(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap B^c) = A \cap B \cap A \cap B^c = (A \cap A) \cap (B \cap B^c) = A \cap ((\Omega - B) \cap B) = A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset,$$

hence $(A \cap B)$ and  $(A \cap B^c)$ are mutually disjoint.

Now that we now this fact we may continue with the main proof.

Using **3.**(c) for these mutually disjoint events we get

$$P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c) = P((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)),$$

but by the distributive property of the intersection over the union we have

$$P((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c))= P(A \cap (B \cup B^c))= P(A \cap (B \cup (\Omega - B))= P(A \cap \Omega)$$

Since $A \in \mathcal{F}$ is a subset of $\Omega$ by definition, we have

$$P(A \cap \Omega) = P(A)$$

Hence $P(A \cap B) + (A \cap B^c) = P(A) \, \blacksquare$